# Test Control+Click with Capybara, Selenium, JS

Tags: jquery, selenium, cucumber, capybara

I'm using jQuery's Selectable ability on a table, which requires (besides lassoing) to control+click to be able to select multiple rows at a time.

I have a custom event handler on the selected event because only when 2 or more rows are selected do I want a certain link to be visible. I want to be able to test this using Cucumber, Capybara, and Selenium.

The trouble is I have found no way to be able to select more than one row during the test. I've found no way to be able to hold control while clicking, and no way to try lassoing. I tried using `drag_to` but to no avail.

Please let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I recall correctly, there is a `controlKeyDown` Selenium command, which should keep the simulated Ctrl key pressed down until `controlKeyUp` command is called.

> `controlKeyDown ( )`
>   Press the control key and hold it down until doControlUp() is called or a new page is loaded.
>
> `controlKeyUp ( )`
>   Release the control key.

Similarly there are `mouseDown` and `mouseDownAt` commands, which do the very same thing to the left mouse button until `mouseUp`.

> `mouseDown ( locator )`
>   Simulates a user pressing the left mouse button (without releasing it yet) on the specified element.
>
> `mouseDownAt ( locator,coordString )`
>   Simulates a user pressing the left mouse button (without releasing it yet) at the specified location.
>
> `mouseMove ( locator )`
>   Simulates a user pressing the mouse button (without releasing it yet) on the specified element.
>
> `mouseMoveAt ( locator,coordString )`
>   Simulates a user pressing the mouse button (without releasing it yet) on the specified element.
>
> `mouseUp ( locator )`
>   Simulates the event that occurs when the user releases the mouse button (i.e., stops holding the button down) on the specified element.
>
> `mouseUpAt ( locator,coordString )`
>   Simulates the event that occurs when the user releases the mouse button (i.e., stops holding the button down) at the specified location.

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html